# How to enter a Googol in Python?

Tags: python, integer, long-integer

I've heard that Python does not have any upper limit with integers. So I wanted to give a try:

```
a = 1e100
b = 1
c = a + b + a
c - 2 * a
> 0.0
```

Unfortunately I realized that writing `1e2` returns a float while `100` returns an int.

I've then tested with `long('1' + '0' * 100)` which works.

```
a = long('1' + '0' * 100)
b = 1
c = a + b + a
c - 2 * a
> 1L
```

Is this solution the only way to affect a [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) to a variable?

Subsequent question:

How to avoid confusion between floating point and fixed point during computations?

Comment: This also works: `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a Googol like so:

```
10**100
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont really understand your question but i think you are asking is there only this way to manipulate googol variable .

i just tried this on my python idle and got this

```
>>> a = 10 ** 100
>>> b = 1
>>> c = a + b + a
>>> c - 2 *a
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the power operator:

```
base**times
```

so 123 googols would be 123*10**100